# Google Sheets script to copy and paste in another sheet after the last record

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a script that will copy a certain range of Sheet A and paste it in Sheet B after the last record, I know it should be pretty easy, but somehow the code is not working, could you please advise me on what am I doing wrong here, it will clear the contents of the cell, but copy partially the data from Sheet A to Sheet B

```
function Export2() {

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      var database = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX");
     var source = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
       var dataToCopy = source.getRange('B2:G10');
      var copyToSheet = database.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
      var lastRow = copyToSheet.getLastRow();
      for (var i = 1; i<6 ;i++){
        var Paste = copyToSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,i).setValues(dataToCopy.getCell(1,i).getValues());
    }

    var Clean = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('B2:G10');
                Clean.clear({contentsOnly:true});
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function Export2() {
  var svA=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(2,2,9,6).getValues()
  var dsh=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1AqQyqMQNnYvbFoU0HQ4WtjqkKtfxkj15Y6iXG6lCWkI').getSheetByName('Sheet2')
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1,svA.length,svA[0].length).setValues(svA);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- You want to copy the values of the range `B2:G10` on `Sheet1` in the active Spreadsheet to the last row of `Sheet2` in the other Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script.
- After the values were copied, you want to clear the cells of the range `B2:G10` on `Sheet1` in the active Spreadsheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your current script, only values of "B2:F2" of the source sheet are copied. So in this case, at first, retrieve the source values from the range `B2:G10` on `Sheet1` in the active Spreadsheet. Then, put the values to the destination range.
- In order to clear the range `B2:G10` on `Sheet1` in the active Spreadsheet, you can also use `dataToCopy` of `var dataToCopy = source.getRange('B2:G10')`.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
function Export2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var database = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX");
  var source = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dataToCopy = source.getRange('B2:G10');
  var copyToSheet = database.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  // I modified below script.
  var sourceValues = dataToCopy.getValues();
  var lastRow = copyToSheet.getLastRow();
  copyToSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceValues);
  dataToCopy.clear({contentsOnly:true});
}
```

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Not at all, thank you for your answer, I guess I explained myself incorrectly, the solution you provided works fine, however what I'm trying to accomplish to is paste the data from Sheet 1 into Sheet 2 below the last row with data, I appreciate your modification

Comment: @Ericksson Moran Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. About `paste the data from Sheet 1 into Sheet 2 below the last row with data`, the modified script retrieves the values from the range `B2:G10` on `Sheet1` in the active Spreadsheet, and then, the values are put to below the last row of `Sheet2`. I would like to correctly understand about your goal and resolve your issue. So can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the sample input and output you expect? By this, I would like to modify it. Of course, please remove your personal information.